# ng-class is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

Following script is not working. I guess i am not missing any thing in it.

https://jsfiddle.net/w62apagc/

```
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('ngapp',[]);
        app.controller('ctrl',
            function ($scope) {

            });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ngapp" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-class="[{'bold': warning}]">adf</div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="warning">
</body>
<style>
    .red {
        color:red;
    }
    .bold{font-weight:bold}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet , Your answer is correct. But what if i want to use two classes.. I was trying some thing like `"[red, {bold: warning}]"` but not working.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Perez for info and changelog link.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v140-rc0-smooth-unwinding-2015-04-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are trying to use is only available from Angular 1.4:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v140-rc0-smooth-unwinding-2015-04-10

If you are using the stable version (1.2), use

```
ng-class="{bold: warning}" class="red"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-class="[{'bold': warning}]"
```

should be

```
ng-class="{'bold': warning}"
```

or simply

```
ng-class="{bold: warning}"
```

It doesn't expect an array of objects. It expects an object, with class names as keys, and booleans as values.

Comment: Thanks, Your answer is correct. But what if i want to use two classes.. I was trying some thing like `"[red, {bold: warning}]"` but not working.

Comment: `class="red" ng-class="{bold: warning}"` or `ng-class="{red: true, bold: warning}"`

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you want add red class on warning,

```
<div ng-class="{bold: warning, red:warning}">adf</div>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="warning">
```

Please check this http://plnkr.co/edit/viH8vf6qkqflp1PozsvT?p=preview